# How can I disable certain system keyboard shortcuts in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kiosk, lubuntu

I'm currently working on a kiosk based on lubuntu (which is basically ubuntu with an LXDE desktop environment) that would be put in public places, such as internet cafés, providing internet access for anyone who inserts a coin. The software that handles all the necessary stuff is no problem since I'm a programmer, but I'm worried about the fact that there are certain keyboard shortcuts that I cannot disable. For instance, if someone presses `Ctrl + Alt + F[1...12]`, then the screen would switch over to a virtual console instead of the desktop that has the browser. Of course it's unlikely that anyone will know about these, but if someone does press one of these system-related keyboard shortcuts, they can screw up the whole kiosk. A restart would fix the problem of course, but it would be nice if I could prevent it from happening.

So can I disable certain system keyboard shortcuts in Linux? Or maybe disable certain keys on the keyboard completely via software? I don't want any user to accidentally (or on purpose) mess around with parts of the system I don't want them to be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

> https://github.com/linux-modder/Community-Kickstarts/blob/master/secure-kickstart.cfg

use the above link a look at lines 122-134 for hints (if this based on 14.10 or 15.04  it has changed to sysD and the /etc/init.d references are now /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-foo